# Motion detector like just dance application in android

Tags: android, android-activity, video-capture, motion-detection

I am creating an application in which i am have to detect motion of body just like just dance application on android. In this application, I want the user to a able to record a (3 - 5
mins. maximum) dance/exercise video that they can send to other users
within a group as a personal challenge.
Can anyone please just give me a rare idea how above feature will be achieved in android.

Thanks

Comment: Check OpenCv in Android. It provides many built-in functions that you may exploit to detect surface, clustering etc. . You can optionally determine the frame rate, pixel definitions so on.

Comment: @metzelder Thanks ...i wll give it a try..